# Deployment Issues with IdentityServer on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, identityserver4

For the past 2weeks - and it pains me so much to say this, I have been trying to deploy a solution with IdentityServer4, API and a Web client to Azure without success. I encountered so many problems in the process but solving one of them just leads me to the next one, leaving me with the current one that I have absolutely no clue about.

Right now, if you log on to the url https://breezeonline.ng, it redirects you to the IdentityServer Application for authentication but when I login, it goes into some sort of inifinte loop trying to redirect to the callback url for a long time and crashes at the end.

In the logs, I see it authenticates the user, issues the token successfully and repeats. Below is a part of the log that explains it

**Log**

```
2018-09-12T12:57:04.082667372Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
2018-09-12T12:57:04.082684972Z Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
2018-09-12T12:57:04.082698872Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086283241Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086293841Z Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086298141Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086482040Z [12:57:04 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086490739Z Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086494739Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086673638Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086682338Z Start authorize request
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086685938Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086917636Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086926336Z User in authorize request: 6f8aded4-5452-404d-8952-72be464c22d7
2018-09-12T12:57:04.086930136Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.087121134Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
2018-09-12T12:57:04.087129634Z Start authorize request protocol validation
2018-09-12T12:57:04.087133134Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.087355832Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
2018-09-12T12:57:04.087380632Z Checking for PKCE parameters
2018-09-12T12:57:04.087384332Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.087586030Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
2018-09-12T12:57:04.087595730Z No PKCE used.
2018-09-12T12:57:04.087599430Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088024626Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088033226Z Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088036926Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088304224Z [12:57:04 Information] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088313024Z ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088316524Z {
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088320024Z   "ClientId": "BreezeWebClient",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088323624Z   "ClientName": "Breeze Web Client",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088327224Z   "RedirectUri": "http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088330824Z   "AllowedRedirectUris": [
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088385323Z     "http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088392323Z     "https://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc"
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088395923Z   ],
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088399323Z   "SubjectId": "6f8aded4-5452-404d-8952-72be464c22d7",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088402923Z   "ResponseType": "code id_token",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088407223Z   "ResponseMode": "form_post",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088423623Z   "GrantType": "hybrid",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088476922Z   "RequestedScopes": "openid profile BreezeApi offline_access",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088518922Z   "State": "CfDJ8N8_2AAgVOJOrHQ43U4UbLtsOv9jds_esgaeJ0OojAk7D5Ue_NjdR8049p2dl1IfR9l1Y4gozSqxu2qhnjHyDrxRyRVLctq90AnIdu5d4UREbYN14Kv5u96BNc8NDuFvW-GM7ufuHRCTKa0_C2Xf1-O7cmZ4lopgGtmnyVMUfZhTWWHl2pC5sWzvE3sK8gxs7szp3fkndoqBZyuqvjyRWpX8-prEgWZQu_2S0X-6Tb5LNFkxZq7hPS_uqNCZZBZY6Kubk6spgEqPlC1aVgJA4lzmf9DPme2p4hfqFl_iiOX-p78cbrRbNCYY4AyS9nMyMoGloGzrRTABi-lTHk3cPZ8",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088585722Z   "Nonce": "636723538239035673.OWZiYTQ3NTktZWU1Mi00MzE1LWEyMjYtMTk2ODBmZTlhOWYxNDkxOTI3MjktZTUxMS00NTY0LWJiYjYtMDFhMjQ3Yjc2MTU3",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088593021Z   "SessionId": "343ad1a8f6b93ca74e26b7d8b8f0ad86",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088596621Z   "Raw": {
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088600121Z     "client_id": "BreezeWebClient",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088603721Z     "redirect_uri": "http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088607221Z     "response_type": "code id_token",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088653521Z     "scope": "openid profile BreezeApi offline_access",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088660021Z     "response_mode": "form_post",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088663621Z     "nonce": "636723538239035673.OWZiYTQ3NTktZWU1Mi00MzE1LWEyMjYtMTk2ODBmZTlhOWYxNDkxOTI3MjktZTUxMS00NTY0LWJiYjYtMDFhMjQ3Yjc2MTU3",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088747920Z     "state": "CfDJ8N8_2AAgVOJOrHQ43U4UbLtsOv9jds_esgaeJ0OojAk7D5Ue_NjdR8049p2dl1IfR9l1Y4gozSqxu2qhnjHyDrxRyRVLctq90AnIdu5d4UREbYN14Kv5u96BNc8NDuFvW-GM7ufuHRCTKa0_C2Xf1-O7cmZ4lopgGtmnyVMUfZhTWWHl2pC5sWzvE3sK8gxs7szp3fkndoqBZyuqvjyRWpX8-prEgWZQu_2S0X-6Tb5LNFkxZq7hPS_uqNCZZBZY6Kubk6spgEqPlC1aVgJA4lzmf9DPme2p4hfqFl_iiOX-p78cbrRbNCYY4AyS9nMyMoGloGzrRTABi-lTHk3cPZ8",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088755120Z     "x-client-SKU": "ID_NETSTANDARD1_4",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088758720Z     "x-client-ver": "5.2.0.0"
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088762220Z   }
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088765620Z }
2018-09-12T12:57:04.088768920Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.223151567Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultConsentService
2018-09-12T12:57:04.223165167Z Client is configured to not require consent, no consent is required
2018-09-12T12:57:04.223192167Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.223466865Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator
2018-09-12T12:57:04.223476264Z Creating Hybrid Flow response.
2018-09-12T12:57:04.223479864Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.364702253Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.PersistedGrantStore
2018-09-12T12:57:04.364715753Z QdTa1gOWgJjAgiGP99GaUJyC2bPoBsV8oxZXv6+GnIY= not found in database
2018-09-12T12:57:04.364719953Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.621719048Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator
2018-09-12T12:57:04.621734248Z Creating Implicit Flow response.
2018-09-12T12:57:04.621756348Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.622154145Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService
2018-09-12T12:57:04.622163445Z Getting claims for identity token for subject: 6f8aded4-5452-404d-8952-72be464c22d7 and client: BreezeWebClient
2018-09-12T12:57:04.622187844Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.622495642Z [12:57:04 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultClaimsService
2018-09-12T12:57:04.622600841Z In addition to an id_token, an access_token was requested. No claims other than sub are included in the id_token. To obtain more user claims, either use the user info endpoint or set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken on the client configuration.
2018-09-12T12:57:04.622608941Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624513325Z [12:57:04 Information] IdentityServer4.Events.DefaultEventService
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624523724Z {
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624527724Z   "Name": "Token Issued Success",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624531724Z   "Category": "Token",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624535524Z   "EventType": "Success",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624539224Z   "Id": 2000,
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624542824Z   "ClientId": "BreezeWebClient",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624546624Z   "ClientName": "Breeze Web Client",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624614324Z   "RedirectUri": "http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624621824Z   "Endpoint": "Authorize",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624625624Z   "SubjectId": "6f8aded4-5452-404d-8952-72be464c22d7",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624637623Z   "Scopes": "openid profile BreezeApi offline_access",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624641423Z   "GrantType": "hybrid",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624645123Z   "Tokens": [
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624648823Z     {
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624652423Z       "TokenType": "id_token",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624707223Z       "TokenValue": "****m2yQ"
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624714123Z     },
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624717823Z     {
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624721323Z       "TokenType": "code",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624725023Z       "TokenValue": "****b585"
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624729423Z     }
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624733123Z   ],
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624736623Z   "ActivityId": "0HLGOLLUFJS8Q:00000001",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624740323Z   "TimeStamp": "2018-09-12T12:57:04Z",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624744523Z   "ProcessId": 1,
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624748122Z   "LocalIpAddress": "::ffff:xx.yy.aa.abc:80",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624805822Z   "RemoteIpAddress": "::ffff:xx.yy.aa.abc"
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624812822Z }
2018-09-12T12:57:04.624816222Z 
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629383683Z [12:57:04 Information] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629420382Z Authorize endpoint response
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629458082Z {
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629463682Z   "SubjectId": "6f8aded4-5452-404d-8952-72be464c22d7",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629467982Z   "ClientId": "BreezeWebClient",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629471982Z   "RedirectUri": "http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629654980Z   "State": "CfDJ8N8_2AAgVOJOrHQ43U4UbLtsOv9jds_esgaeJ0OojAk7D5Ue_NjdR8049p2dl1IfR9l1Y4gozSqxu2qhnjHyDrxRyRVLctq90AnIdu5d4UREbYN14Kv5u96BNc8NDuFvW-GM7ufuHRCTKa0_C2Xf1-O7cmZ4lopgGtmnyVMUfZhTWWHl2pC5sWzvE3sK8gxs7szp3fkndoqBZyuqvjyRWpX8-prEgWZQu_2S0X-6Tb5LNFkxZq7hPS_uqNCZZBZY6Kubk6spgEqPlC1aVgJA4lzmf9DPme2p4hfqFl_iiOX-p78cbrRbNCYY4AyS9nMyMoGloGzrRTABi-lTHk3cPZ8",
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629663480Z   "Scope": "openid profile BreezeApi offline_access"
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629667480Z }
2018-09-12T12:57:04.629670880Z
```

You can also take a look at the IdentityServer Configuration in Startup for IdentityServer and the Web Client

**IdentityServer Startup.cs**

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    if (!Environment.IsDevelopment())
        options.PublicOrigin = Configuration["HostSettings:RemotePublicOrigin"];
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1800);
})
    //.AddSigningCredential(cert)
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = db => db.UseNpgsql(connectionString,
            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    })
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = db =>
            db.UseNpgsql(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    })
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddConfigurationStoreCache()
    .AddProfileService<OAuthProfileService>();

if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}
else
{

    X509Certificate2 cert = null;
    using (X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
            X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
            "**Retracted thumbprint**",
            false);
        // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
        if (certCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            cert = certCollection[0];
            Log.Logger.Information($"Successfully loaded cert from registry: {cert.Thumbprint}");
        }
    }
    if (cert == null)
    {
        cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, "5f2d3bb6331537975a0a195996182c34.pfx"), "breeze");
        Log.Logger.Information($"Falling back to cert from file. Successfully loaded: {cert.Thumbprint}");
    }

    builder.AddSigningCredential(cert);
}
```

**Client Config**

```
{
    "ClientId": "BreezeWebClient",
    "ClientName": "Breeze Web Client",
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "RedirectUris": [
      "https://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc",
      "http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "version": "20"
    },
    "FrontChannelLogoutUri": "https://breezeonline.ng/signout-oidc",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
      "https://breezeonline.ng/signout-callback-oidc",
      "http://breezeonline.ng/signout-callback-oidc"
    ],
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true,
    "AllowedScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
      "address",
      "phone",
      "offline_access",
      "BreezeApi",
      "openidc"
    ],
    "AccessTokenLifetime": 1800,
    "IdentityTokenLifetime": 1800,
    "AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime": 1800,
    "SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime": 1800
  }
```

For the `RedirectUris` and `PostLogoutRedirectUris`, I had to include http:// for both because it was throwing an Unauthorized client error eve after setting `RequireHttpsMetadata` to `true`.

Web Client Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = idSvrUrl;
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    else
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.ClientId = "BreezeWebClient";
    options.ClientSecret = "**My Secret**";

    options.ClaimActions.Add(new RoleClaimAction());
    options.ClaimActions.Add(new FullNameClaimAction());
    options.ClaimActions.Add(new RoleSubClaimAction());
    options.ClaimActions.Add(new CompanyIdClaimAction());

    options.ResponseType = OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.CodeIdToken;

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.Scope.Add("BreezeApi");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
    };
});
```

So that's it. I don't know where I've gone wrong. I need not mention that this works flawlessly on localhost. Please help.

Comment: I tried to open your site but got this in address bar without doing anything : `https://applicationhost.breezeonline.ng/account/login?returnUrl=/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=BreezeWebClient&redirect_uri=http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc&response_type=codeid_token&scope=openidprofileBreezeApioffline_access&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636724122191637437.MjBjZjkxN2UtYmVjMi00NzVhLTllZmMtOGRkYzUxYmEyNGM3N2I5NDA1ZjYtMTQ0MC00YTc2LTk4MTUtOTI0MjkxMDA2MTNi&state=CfDJ8N8_WAY_TOO_LONG_FOR_COMMENT&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0`

Comment: Seems to much going on just for reaching login page `https://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc`

Comment: Got your point, I am getting infinite loop with redirect to both `http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc` & `https://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc` with HTTP 301 & 302

Comment: There is one thing I feel wrong in request `http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc` cookie in request headers is repeating same data over & over again till header maximum length is exceeds. If we can remove http request, https seems to be working fine

Comment: Your idea seems right. But initially I had only `https://...` in the `AllowedRedirectUris` but it threw an error stating "Unauthorised Client" and in the logs, I discovered it was trying to redirect to `http://...` which wasn't allowed. I don't know why it would wanna do that after setting it to https everywhere it should be setup on startup and client, still to no avail. I had to add it to the list of alloweduris to at least get it to the login page and now this. How do you think I can allow only https only to make it work?

Comment: Can you join https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83100/deployment-issues-with-identityserver-on-azure for a min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution. The problem was just a redirect problem. All I did was to remove `http://breezeonline.ng/signin-oidc` from the client config file and adding the following code to startup.cs in the MVC project under `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` and `app.UseAuthentication()`

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
   ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

An just like that, my battle with azure deployment since 2 weeks was won.

Comment: Just encountered this same problem, you are my hero. Worked perfectly for docker image hosted on azure web app for containers with ssl set on the web app, the container runs under port 80, so I was stuck with invalid_redirect uri error because it was sent as http not https. Adding this finally got it working.